# Changing an endpoint method's request message class doesn't update the method

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to update an endpoint which I have defined previously as follows:

```
class NestedMessage(messages.Message):
  foo = messages.StringField(1)

MyResource = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
  message_types.VoidMessage,
  param1=messages.StringField(1, required=True),
  param2=messages.StringField(2),
  param3=messages.MessageField(NestedMessage, 3)
)

class MyApi(remote.Service):
  @endpoints.method(MyResource, messages.VoidMessage,
                    path='new', http_method='POST', name='new')
  def new(self, request):
    # ...
    return messages.VoidMessage
```

I need to change from using a `ResourceContainer` to a `Message` class instead (it was unclear which one to use for `POST` methods).

So I try and update to this:

```
# NestedMessage unchanged
class NestedMessage(messages.Message):
  foo = messages.StringField(1)

class MyMessage(messages.Message):
  param1 = messages.StringField(1, required=True)
  param2 = messages.StringField(2)
  param3 = messages.MessageField(NestedMessage, 3)

class MyApi(remote.Service):
  @endpoints.method(MyMessage, messages.VoidMessage,
                    path='new', http_method='POST', name='new')
  def new(self, request):
    # ...
    return messages.VoidMessage
```

But when I try the endpoint in `/_ah/api/explorer`, it just shows a blank page. Checking the result of `discovery.apis.getRest` on my api, the new `MyMessage` class isn't listed, and the `MyApi.new` method is borked due to not having a resource container.

Renaming the method to something else (e.g. `MyApi.create`) works, but then it breaks the `MyApi.new` method.

Is there a way to "force" Cloud Endpoints to update all methods?

**EDIT** This is both on development (localhost) and when deploying.

**EDIT 2** It seems the issue only happens with API Explorer. Using the updated endpoint (via the Javascript library for example) uses the working, updated method.

**EDIT 3** No wait, I've updated two endpoint methods. Now, both of them are showing fine in API Explorer, but one of them still seems to be "broken" when used with the Javascript client library (i.e. POST payload is passed as URL query parameters, not as JSON body). The other is behaving correctly. What is going on?

Comment: This question is very confusing due to your edits. Please just edit the entire question to explain what is currently happening to you, the development environment you are using, and what concrete steps you are taking to reproduce the issue you're seeing.

Comment: If you've already figured out what was wrong, it's good SO etiquette to return to the issue and identify what you did to fix the problem.

If you are still having trouble, please edit your question to be as clear as possible. At present I find it very difficult to follow the order in which events occurred, and the current state of your code, or even what the current errors are. This is a very low quality question at present due to the unclear language and multiple edits (also, does your API class even have the `@endpoints.api` annotation?)